# Jmeter - How to randomize jdbc query with values from range when using Select statement

Tags: jmeter

Having database like:

[image]

[image]

I want to randomize my query so will return a random ID between 10000 and 100119.
What is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can do it on your database/SQL query level like [ORDER BY RANDOM](https://www.javatpoint.com/sql-order-by-random) implementation for your DBMS system, additionally you can [LIMIT](https://www.javatpoint.com/sql-order-by-limit) the output to 1 row only
2. You can do this with JMeter, if you provide `Id` as the "Variable Names"

   [image]

   you will be able to get the random match using [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) functions combination like:

   ```
   ${__V(Id_${__Random(1,${Id_#},)},)}
   ```

   More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Even though @Dmitri T answer was very helpful, what was the best for me considering I need from the specific range is:

```
SELECT *
FROM [test] 
where picktypeid=6 and Description like '${__Random(1,120)}'
```

then use as: Id_1 && Description_1